# Backbone Marionette focus event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I want to use focus/blur events to show/hide an area containing a textarea.

In my template:

```
<div class="area">
    <textarea/>
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="action"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my Backbone Marionette view:

```
events: {
    'focus .area': 'onFocus',
    'blur .area': 'onBlur',
    'click .action': 'onAction'
},
```

Why the focus does not work on my template when I do click on `.zone` div (but in the `textarea` instead) ? And why the click event is never executed (but the blur is instead) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to add `tabIndex` and make `div.area` as a form component:

```
<div class="area" tabIndex="0">
    <textarea/>
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="action"/>
    </div>
</div>
```